# Sort Array data Alphabetically

Tags: ios, sorting

I am Working on sorting the data which I'm getting from array. And Sorting process in working properly using code

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
 [self.array_ sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

But initially the list of all that element is coming which start from capital letter and then the list of list of that element which start from small letter.But there is requirement for me to arrange the small or capital letter data together.How i can solve this problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Create your sortDescriptor like this and pass to array.

```
NSSortDescriptor * sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
[self.array_ sortUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
```